# Application Servers Maximum Memory Limit

Tags: java, memory, jboss, limit, max

How much memory can a server (Jboss, Tomcat etc...) use? For example if the server has 128gb memory, can it use at least 100gb of it? I'm using these parameters for my local:

```
-Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512
```

Can these parameters configured for usage of 100gb?

Comment: Hope my answer helped. This isn't specific to JBoss though, perhaps you can edit the question to specify Java?

Comment: Your answer is related with java but my question doesnt. I heard that tomcat max memory limit cant be increased as much as JBoss. That is why i asked this question. Maybe you heard about tomcats max memory limit issue?

Comment: There's no difference between JBoss and Tomcat in terms of which can use more memory. Both are limited by how much memory Java is configured for.

Comment: Ok then, i will edit the question to specify Java. People can benefit more with this way. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We use this to run a 24GB 64-bit JVM with sub-second GC pauses while serving 100+ page requests per second:

```
-Xms24g -Xmx24g -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:NewRatio=4 -XX:SurvivorRatio=8    
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+DisableExplicitGC  
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled  
-XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=68
```

There shouldn't be any reason you can't specify 100GB if you server has the memory. Since we're using under 32GB we also use `-XX:+UseCompressedOops` to reduce the overhead of 64-bit addressing. Additionally we use `-XX:+UseLargePages` for better performance, however you have to enable large page support for your OS first.

Answer (score 4):

As Mat said, those huge heaps could get problematic with Garbage Collection, but then with a large heap, you probably are using a multi-core machine, where you can use a collector that basically runs on a core of its own.

Otherwise -Xm accepts a unit of 'g' so you can write `-Xmx100g`

Manpage for java (on OS X ) says:

> On Mac OS X platforms, the upper
>   limit for this value when running in
>   32-bit mode (-d32)  is  approximately
>                              2100m  minus  overhead  amounts,  and
>   approximately 127t minus overhead
>   amounts when running in 64-bit mode
>                              (-d64).  On Solaris 7 and Solaris 8 SPARC
>   platforms, the upper limit for this
>   value is approximately  4000m
>                              minus  overhead  amounts.  On  Solaris  2.6
>   and x86 platforms, the upper limit is
>   approximately 2000m minus
>                              overhead amounts. On Linux platforms, the upper
>   limit is approximately 2000m minus
>   overhead amounts.

Answer (score 3):

You'll run into (probably) dramatic GC pauses for that kind of heap size.
(Aside from that, I don't know of hard limitations as long as you're running a 64bit VM of course)

Not directly related to your question, but I found this [Google TechTalks video on Ehcache](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TszcAWgCXD0&feature=channel_video_title) interesting - Greg Luck talks about heap size issues in there.